# Custom Search Filter - Yajra Datatables Service

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, datatables, yajra-datatable

I am working on **yajra** data tables. We use it as a service, I'm wondering if it's possible to make a custom filter search for it? Any links or suggestions?

**Here's my code:**

```
public function dataTable($query)
{
    $datatables = datatables()->eloquent($query);
    return $datatables;
}

public function query()
{
    $report= AdminReport::select();

    return $this->applyScopes($report);
}

public function html()
{
    return $this->builder()
                ->setTableId('admin-reports-table')
                ->columns($this->getColumns())
                ->minifiedAjax()
                ->dom('Bflrtip')
                ->orderBy(0);
}

protected function getColumns()
{
    return [
        'id' => ['title' => 'ID #'],
        'player_name' => ['title' => 'Player Name'],
        'balance' => ['title' => 'Current Balance'],
    ];
}
```

Here's my frontend: `index.blade.php`

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <form class="form-inline" method="post" autocomplete="off" action=" 
          {{url('admin_report/filter') }}">
          <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="date_range" placeholder="Date Range">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Query</button>
        </form>                  
      </div>                            
     </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- DATATABLE -->
<div class="content">
   <div class="container-fluid">
       {{$dataTable->table(['class'=>'table table-bordered table-hover'])}}
   </div>
</div>

@push('scripts')
    {{$dataTable->scripts()}}
@endpush
```

I just want to ask how can I implement custom search filter for this approach.

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: What do you mean by custom search filter? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Perhaps these will help you: https://datatables.yajrabox.com/  | https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/engine-eloquent

Comment: @user8555937 , i want an input type where the user can put what they want to search to the table, then submit it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working on a similar case, this is what I have on code and it works 100%. In my instance I am filtering my results based on date range inputs. I've only highlighted the important parts, please use in conjunction with Yajra docs and DataTable.net docs. I'm also using [Keentheme's metronic admin template](https://keenthemes.com/metronic/), it's well maintained and well documented

### app/DataTable NameXclass.php

```
public function dataTable($query, Request $request)
{
    return datatables()
        ->eloquent($query)
        ->filterColumn('created_at', function ($query, $keywords) use ($request) {
            if (!$request->has('joined_between')) {
                return; //ignore if there are no dates
            }
            switch (sizeof($request->joined_between)){
                case 1: //do this if only 1 date is provided
                    $start = new Carbon($request->joined_between[0]);
                    $query->whereDate('created_at','=', $start);
                    break;
                case 2: //do this if both dates are provided
                    if($request->joined_between[0] == $request->joined_between[1]){
                        $start = new Carbon($request->joined_between[0]);
                        $query->whereDate('created_at','=', $start);
                    }else{
                        $query->whereBetween('created_at', $request->joined_between);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        });
}
```

### index.blade.php

A few required things to note here: datatable-input is the css class I use to refer to the inputs in js, name attributes are used in php to get the values from the request (see code above I passed the $request object), and data-col-index attribute is required by yajra datatable to map the filters to the correct column. I made a mistake of not including/mapping them correctly and I struggled for a week to figure out what I was doing wrong. So bear in mind, and don't be like me

```
<div class="input-daterange input-group" id="kt_datepicker">
   <input type="text" class="form-control datatable-input" name="start" placeholder="From" data-col-index="2" />
   <input type="text" class="form-control datatable-input" name="end" placeholder="To" data-col-index="2" />
</div>
```

### .js

```
//columns .. data-col-index=2 maps to created_at
var columns = [
    {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
    {data: 'appointmentable_type', name: 'appointmentable_type'},
    {data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at'},
    {data: 'updated_at', name: 'updated_at'},
]
...
//The search button event listener
$('#search').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var params = {};
    $('.datatable-input').each(function() {
        var i = $(this).data('col-index');
        if (params[i]) {
            params[i] += '|' + $(this).val();
        }
        else {
            params[i] = $(this).val();
        }
    });
    $.each(params, function(i, val) {
        // apply search params to datatable
        table.column(i).search(val ? val : '', false, false);
    });
    table.table().draw();
});
```

Comment: Oh yeah... I forgot to include this snippet which must be passed to the .DataTable({}) init object on your .js file. I'm using it to submit the dates

`
ajax: {
    data: function(d){
        let range = [];
        range.push(moment($('input[name=start]').val()).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')):'';
        range.push(moment(input[name=end]').val() + ' 23:59:59').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')):'';
        d.joined_between = range;
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official docs](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/filter-column), you can use `filterColumn` to implement a custom search for a specific column.

OR you can use [manual search](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/manual-search) to write your own manual filtering functions and thus disabling global search of the package.

You can also check this similar [issue](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/issues/416) on github.